# How to change the text box value Using NSIS Script?

Tags: nsis

I am new to NSIS Script and creating installers.

In My page there is a text box. While the page loading the text box show the value of reading the text from one text file. I want to know how to do this Using NSIS Scripts.. Need code samples...

Comment: Mind showing some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function .onInit
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$pluginsdir\text.txt" w ; Normally the text file would come from a File command
FileWrite $0 "Hello World$\r$\nfrom$\r$\nNSIS$\r$\n" ; Add some dummy text
FileClose $0
FunctionEnd

Page Custom MyCustomPageInit
Page InstFiles

Var TxtCtl

!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function MyCustomPageInit
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

!define MYMULTILINEEDIT_STYLE ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${ES_AUTOHSCROLL}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_READONLY}
nsDialogs::CreateControl EDIT ${MYMULTILINEEDIT_STYLE} ${WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE}|${WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE} 5% 10u 90% 50% ""
Pop $TxtCtl

FileOpen $0 "$pluginsdir\text.txt" r
loop:
    FileRead $0 $1 ; Read a line
    IfErrors eof
    SendMessage $TxtCtl ${EM_REPLACESEL} 0 "STR:$1$\n"
    Goto loop
eof:
FileClose $0

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: In the above code where we assigning the value to the text box?

Comment: EM_REPLACESEL (There is no selection to replace but I used it since we are reading line by line, use NSD_SetText to set a small amount of text...)